# How to serialize a C# empty list into a JSON empty array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, json.net

I am switching my code from using a property called `floatedPlugin` to using a property called `floatedPlugins` (note the 's'). I don't need `floatedPlugin` to exist at all after this code runs. An existing `floatedPlugin` value will either be an object or `null`. If it's `null`, I want to set `floatedPlugins` to be an empty array. If `floatedPlugin` is an object, I want to set `floatedPlugins` to an array containing solely that object.

```
foreach (var _case in context.Cases)
{
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_case.Data);

    foreach (var row in data.myRows)
    {
        foreach (var plugin in row.plugins)
        {
            if (plugin.floatedPlugin == null)
            {
                 plugin.floatedPlugins = new List<dynamic>(); // Code breaks here
            }
            else
            {
                 plugin.floatedPlugins = new List<dynamic>(plugin.floatedPlugin);
            }
        }
    }
    _case.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}
```

The error I get when trying to run this is

```
Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object].

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object].
```

What do I need to do to get `floatedPlugins` to serialize into `[]` in the resulting serialized JSON?

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Voted to close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dynamic` value that you are dealing with is really `JObject` under the hood. It knows how to automatically convert some standard types (like `int`s) to the appropriate `JValue` objects, but anything more complicated needs to be explicitly turned into some kind of `JToken` first.

```
plugin.floatedPlugins = JArray.FromObject(new List<dynamic>());
```